# Pacman doesn't download anything - Always 404

Tags: arch-linux, updates, package-management, packages

I want to install some software on my Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux, but I keep getting error 404.

I did some research and found that I needed to do `pacman -Syy` and `pacman -Syu`...

When I run `pacman -Syy` with all mirrors enabled, I get:

```
# pacman -Syy
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.aarnet.edu.au : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from ftp.iinet.net.au : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.internode.on.net : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.optus.net : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.rackcentral.com.au : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from syd.mirror.rackspace.com : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from ftp.swin.edu.au : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.mirror.uber.com.au : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror1.htu.tugraz.at : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirrors.ispros.com.bd : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from ftp.byfly.by : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.datacenter.by : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.cu.be : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.mirror.kangaroot.net : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.c3sl.ufpr.br : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from www.las.ic.unicamp.br : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found`
```

I have checked, it says this for the entire `core.db` file, on all mirrors, and for `extra.db`, `community.db` and `aur.db`.

I am able to ping various servers, so I have internet. Also, I am doing this over SSH on a home network.

EDIT: I am not using a proxy server.

If it helps, I am able to use `rankmirrors` which downloads a list of mirrors and uncomments some of them for use, I presume that this is based upon speed.

Comment: Are you using any proxy?

Comment: No, just a router, no proxy, unless my ISP is using one, but I personally, am not.

Comment: Can you open webpages in lynx or links? (I ask because pacman and links/lynx use HTTP, whereas SSH and ping do not.)

Comment: I don't have those. If I type either lynx or links into bash, I get command not found. I imagine that I would use `pacman -S lynx` to get it, but `pacman`'s not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `curl` (it's part of the core, so should be installed) to download the core.db file using the command below. This will help rule out whether your problem is related to `pacman` and/or its configuration, or whether your problem is related to your Internet connection.

```
curl -O http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/core.db
```

If core.db successfully downloads, open it in a text editor (`nano core.db` or even `less core.db`). If the contents look similar to this HTML below (specifically saying `404 Not Found` somewhere in the contents), then it's probably your pacman configuration. I would download the latest Arch Installation CD and re-install pacman from that.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /pub/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/core.db was not foun$
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 8080</address>
</body></html>
```

If core.db fails to download, then it's your Internet connection. Post any error messages you receive and we can help you further troubleshoot.

Also, run this command command

```
cat /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist | grep aarnet.edu.au
```

and verify the output matches this

```
Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

If it does not, download the latest mirror list and uncomment your mirrors. You can do this quickly using this command (you'll still need to open it in a text editor and uncomment the lines `Server = ...` lines).

```
sudo mv /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist~ && curl -o /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/?country=AU
```

If after doing this, `pacman -Syy` still fails, then it's my opinion your installation of pacman is completely broken. Follow the [instructions on the Arch Wiki to re-install pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#pacman_is_completely_broken.21_How_do_I_reinstall_it.3F).

Comment: It looks like this:`^B▒^▒/^^G▒▒gp^▒;▒Wi?^▒▒*c^?▒?^▒▒▒>^?/^R▒=▒^▒▒Oj^A▒c▒^_▒▒^▒▒▒▒b▒^G▒^▒▒^_b▒▒▒3N`

Comment: Actually, it's a long file, but there's a char limit. It _all_ looks like the above though.

Comment: Then it successfully downloaded the core.db file, and you've verified it's not your Internet connection. I've updated my answer to include some more steps.

Comment: In the curl command I had to drop the `www.`, add `"` before and after the url and change `AU` to `NO`.

Answer (score 10):

Use mirror reflector

```
sudo pacman -S reflector
```

Install it and type:

```
sudo reflector -l 5 --sort rate --save /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

Answer (score 5):

For the record, if you are not an ARM user, you may have a 32 bit Arch Linux, but the i686 support ended.

`$ pacman -Syu --debug`

If you see i686 in the repo URLs, then you should switch to [Arch Linux 32](https://bbs.archlinux32.org/viewtopic.php?id=208). Basically you can use its mirrorlist instead of the official one.

Comment: The question States this is on a Raspberry Pi, they run on ARM.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. However, Google links to this question by a native search for pacman and 404 so I think it still worth to keep it here. I edit the answer for more clarification.

Comment: Interestingly, `pacman -Syyu` worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today with my new Raspberry Pi 4.
In my case, pacman-mirrors generated URLs ending with

```
.../$arch/$repo
```

but it should, in fact, be

```
.../$repo/$arch
```

hence the 404 error during the download.

Comment: or maybe (like in my case) you have to update pacman-mirrors first because of a structure change

Link: http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/manjaro-arm/repo/stable/core/aarch64/ and search for "mirror-list" 
then install it with
`sudo pacman -U http://ftp-osl.osuosl.org/pub/manjaro-arm/repo/stable/aarch64/core/pacman-mirrorlist-20200225-1-any.pkg.tar.xz` (there maybe newer version if this link fails)

Comment: I manually modified the mirror list (`/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`) to repair this for the first mirror, and then did a full upgrade (`sudo pacman -Syu`).

Answer (score 0):

If you run Arch inside **VMWare or Virtualbox** check your **firewall and antivirus** settings of main system.

Maybe useful to turn on Internet Connection Sharing for systems which has that restrictions: http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2011/07/12/how-to-fix-vmware-connectivity-problems-after-installing-avast-internet-security/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very issue; what I found was that the nameserver (OpenNIC) I was using wasn't resolving the URLs on the mirrorlist.

I edited /etc/resolv.conf, added another DNS server that properly resolved URLs and pacman successfully updated:

```
GNU nano 2.5.3                          File: /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 104.238.153.178
nameserver //add new DNS server here//
```

If your resolv.conf says:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
```

You'll need to modify /etc/resolvconf.conf to make these changes permanent:

```
GNU nano 2.5.3                         File: /etc/resolvconf.conf

name_servers=//add new DNS server here//
```

I have yet to find a /etc/resolvconfconf.conf or /etc/resolvconfconfconf.conf, so if resolving URLs is the issue, the above steps should take care of it. Good luck! :-)