# After Upgrade: Pacman error 404

Tags: linux, arch-linux, updates, raspberry-pi, package-management

I've upgraded Arch Linux on my Raspberry, and now receiving following error every time I want to update my system with `pacman -Syu`:

```
    :: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.easyname.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror1.htu.tugraz.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.easyname.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror1.htu.tugraz.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.23media.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.limun.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.limun.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from artfiles.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror5.bastelfreak.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from ftp.fau.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from ftp.fau.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.flipez.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.fluxent.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.fs.cx : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.fs.cx : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.openlabto.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.beccacervello.it : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirrors.prometeus.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed to update core (unexpected error)
```

My raspberry does have a working internet connection (Internet-SSH connection, ping works), the Mirrorlist is up-to-date. I followed the instruction in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/795472/pacman-doesnt-download-anything-always-404), downloading the core.db (with `curl -O http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/core.db`) works, but when opening the file it seems damaged:

```
^_^▒^H^@▒▒▒U^@^C▒▒^֣L▒&X▒▒^T▒▒▒]K▒^N▒^D^▒^▒▒t▒^AM ▒y▒▒^E^▒!^P▒^X^Ĥ^˾▒g▒^▒~^▒Z▒^^▒▒1▒^U^▒G▒^▒▒8^?^^▒▒▒▒^▒0▒C▒▒▒▒m▒^▒I^▒'▒^L^▒1x^B▒^?▒=▒▒^▒q▒▒.^▒^▒\▒▒^BB▒▒^ߤ&^@^@^A^B^X^B▒▒$
OG^▒▒▒^D='▒▒▒|^▒^▒▒j▒^?▒▒▒y▒^▒L{▒▒▒>|^ZQ]▒v^▒▒▒>(^Բ,▒▒8▒▒8▒^E^^▒▒^▒▒^K▒▒c▒^?▒^[▒^▒V?▒▒Ȯ▒̴▒▒▒▒L{^▒▒▒^B^▒^R▒<▒▒▒^Z▒X^▒^▒▒Ho▒▒\▒.`▒^R,^^R^Q^▒Ԣ^T^▒▒1E               ▒▒qd▒^֫[▒]^E`r▒$
Oft▒&^X▒^_▒
^Z~^^▒^E^\V▒״▒^▒Z^ūj_^F}^▒^?X^Pd^ľ▒?^▒'^▒▒7▒O▒lFyh^B J^B▒6^▒^▒^L▒HM^Y8H^▒▒▒^▒d2^▒^▒^▒▒b^E"% ▒^R^Ϡ^▒E▒iJ▒^Cm^Q▒^▒a▒▒▒▒^▒J▒^▒e[▒M▒^P^▒9▒^U▒k_▒_S▒¿^E^ݺ▒+▒▒J▒^▒/V▒J}▒^▒▒r@A▒$
c▒|▒▒▒,▒^V^▒^▒VI▒▒▒)5^▒b▒^_▒▒^OJC/▒^C}▒▒▒_o▒JVa^▒O▒▒▒^Up▒R▒▒^▒s▒▒▒^V▒TZ}^GZ^P^▒H^ԫ▒▒^Uh1<^֦▒6▒n▒▒▒▒▒^▒▒▒^[▒b▒^?▒k▒^▒7▒▒_▒^O|▒▒wo▒/^?^Bx▒▒▒!^W▒▒▒▒▒'▒:▒w'?^▒▒^DL^D^AaD.▒^?^Q$
Su%▒`2▒▒^VA▒%Iw▒uQ▒^^B^▒;^U
▒^S8=^̭^S7^X*▒^H^M▒6^A▒▒VH▒^@8S▒^ٯ^\e▒▒▒^▒N▒h▒▒|^▒^▒▒?▒^D^^▒▒L▒▒V^▒x<.▒`▒▒▒▒0nw▒^▒B▒▒^X▒▒^▒▒▒Q^_^HR▒▒G▒v4Dv▒▒^▒▒׼▒^Wl^▒e▒5^[+▒▒▒▒▒▒▒d▒▒i<:2w▒▒^▒`Rv▒45[▒B▒.F>^]▒▒HmӸXQ▒^C^$
▒▒^▒▒^VA^˭▒▒▒6▒▒k▒▒▒)▒.▒8▒▒^B▒▒^▒X^YNZY▒s6y{z8▒KNt▒▒V^C▒^▒▒Z▒^▒▒▒e▒▒#▒?▒R^XA^▒▒W▒▒▒▒▒Oo^▒▒^▒ro▒^?G^@▒[▒▒w▒^_C^^=▒▒{▒^▒▒▒me^▒▒▒^G▒/▒▒▒▒▒▒5]^Y▒▒^▒fy▒^▒▒c^▒▒▒▒,▒^▒▒^▒S▒^AD▒M!`$
&▒<^▒m▒M        W^▒S▒zO&X ▒^['^C^_^▒▒,^U▒▒^▒^Y^Z▒▒m▒=▒^▒▒h<▒)▒▒▒3▒^Ǳ^Wt▒|▒^D▒6^^mN▒v^MT▒^▒w▒^▒▒η^▒▒▒^▒]▒^O▒bx^Pg▒|▒^\▒L▒^ɵXO^F▒4^▒^[▒n▒l-+▒l▒▒w^\׳▒^▒^N^▒=▒^ݸ▒f295[▒^▒▒$
▒▒ek:^C^^R^▒Z▒^▒{xR▒▒^T▒▒^F^▒▒T▒▒▒+^F^_wB▒$▒▒^̩^^\z^\▒]^?^▒▒^▒^▒j6h^▒Ns^L▒q;^MR▒I^ڧ▒I٬"▒[▒^▒▒^▒8k▒▒,^▒3O▒#?^▒^▒Գ%&▒^G▒▒▒H▒^▒▒▒^MFnfm6▒c▒]▒▒^▒^V^▒E6▒?^Q▒▒Hu^▒^▒^X^K;▒▒Q^$
▒▒▒C^\/`▒^▒п^▒▒71A^UB'^P▒B^?▒▒"▒T̢&^@▒Elf2▒^▒Q^▒▒^]^Kat^G▒^Y^S           /آ^Ly^BdS2qu▒^A^R%^TcG ^▒M▒Ml^▒^Aʳ^▒$H^V0     /^▒&EH▒▒▒^▒^▒▒▒▒^▒▒C▒(▒^\^▒^Z^G^▒c▒^?^▒c^▒?▒▒H[▒3i$▒-▒$
▒▒i?▒g^?▒;ѹ▒&j▒▒^G^Z▒e^R^A▒▒▒^▒^▒^GZ▒il^K϶Nd▒[*^▒1▒[▒▒rGik<▒i^▒&▒▒^Z▒▒Vuz▒▒▒`^▒z▒▒▒I+^ٱS▒^B<I▒)▒N▒d▒▒^C▒▒`^Z▒Z▒^▒^̩^▒δc▒s^X▒▒Fo^\▒^ƽ▒,^▒^Z^▒▒▒▒fT▒|▒_^▒▒CBi/▒▒▒y+▒▒^W▒4▒$
-O▒{¡▒,▒^D^D6^▒^KsWf^▒▒z▒^HA▒/▒▒-▒▒?▒{c▒>^▒^▒N^▒?^▒▒4^ZF▒▒P4i▒▒^ʤ▒▒▒~^^LA▒)l▒^H^▒^▒^▒^_▒^▒^▒▒▒^▒▒/▒n^^^F▒^▒▒^ǠR^Ft▒;▒b▒^[f^▒▒▒▒^Q^▒^^▒▒^L/▒▒^▒^▒▒J>▒▒▒^▒▒▒▒▒▒^▒^@▒▒^_▒▒▒G▒▒{$
▒YO▒"▒^Ts▒▒J^@▒▒▒^^^P?▒^U▒▒ʷ▒▒▒v^A▒▒▒▒5▒▒v▒c▒^▒▒{^_▒▒▒▒▒#^W▒▒{▒*▒^^▒▒^▒^Af,▒▒N-I▒mj^▒Y-^▒kf^ֱ▒
ص▒khF^R^Df▒j▒^S/^▒!.Wc▒^▒r^▒^▒▒@D0&▒^^C U▒&^▒▒▒^BQ^▒^@cZ▒▒^▒S^S▒^RmB^\▒^D▒RK&^R▒▒m^@,p▒>^▒Ԧ^▒▒▒^R^H^@^▒B"^▒H""^P^]▒D[▒▒▒#^▒e^L ▒▒^▒p^X`▒^▒0r~P2▒T▒▒▒^▒▒▒▒^▒▒R▒P▒z^▒u6=kUd$
▒^▒^▒BY^Z▒▒▒▒:▒▒▒7▒^\oX6▒▒u▒y֤▒Z^NV:▒▒(▒▒^M-%▒▒&^͡4^▒^▒Sxlۺ▒8▒▒^▒▒▒^H^V@^▒▒▒^▒^▒M^L@{sL▒.Sۭ,`▒~lNNV^R▒U^▒V▒^▒8^▒^GZ▒^▒%_▒c▒<G▒^Υ^^▒▒1▒W{^▒▒▒^▒▒▒^▒▒(F▒▒▒▒^▒~▒^▒6HS>▒^▒▒$
▒^ݸ^▒l▒^Rvp%^B4▒▒^UWL^▒qe^▒▒▒4.^▒^̫4▒▒▒A▒▒▒▒^O^RY^▒▒}{^▒px▒7▒▒?^▒▒▒j▒G^▒▒▒▒^▒G▒▒^?n▒▒▒▒^▒.^Gt▒^Sz^V^▒▒o8^E▒9▒^ϱ^▒^▒(^▒^W▒^▒^_▒▒"▒^▒▒_M^@▒▒▒^A@▒n▒▒▒▒▒▒▒~▒▒▒_▒▒^▒^H▒^׻$
d^▒@^@$^▒^@^▒^Wd^▒:2▒▒~o}^[▒^▒^▒^▒▒^▒▒[;*▒^H1W,▒▒▒^▒^▒2Yuͳ^CQ^Qױ
^\9>^^▒u=AS^▒bG@▒^▒j▒Z▒^Y^▒@^Y▒M;^n^D▒t▒▒^▒▒0E▒^]▒^V▒▒▒▒▒^▒^M▒Jr▒^W-^▒6׾▒▒▒^A^Ѹ▒Z▒ͳ^▒%9   ^T^V▒▒▒^▒▒▒>^D9▒gZ^▒W4^▒:>▒^▒^▒▒ζ▒▒O▒,h^O▒n4/▒▒`▒^н▒▒$ҵl▒V▒n^▒@▒^XY▒▒x▒^L$
.▒X6▒^▒^▒^\▒a▒f^▒4▒O▒"8^▒^▒^[▒^▒k▒N▒|N▒^^WH▒J▒▒▒u^Q?^▒^▒▒▒&Q~U$▒^▒X^H"^K^▒^▒ɯ(▒▒^?▒^?^▒^▒U▒<▒iť^ML▒▒4{▒^▒^U^T▒▒▒▒bbw^Q^Q7^[P^QU▒^U<▒▒▒f▒▒▒▒^D▒-▒^G▒▒?▒▒?^F^▒▒w^▒{▒^W\▒5y▒$
"B^▒^?▒▒^F^▒▒^O▒"▒▒▒▒▒^?▒k▒▒▒▒GX▒^▒▒▒=▒^▒▒ݪ▒^▒^▒▒▒▒g>▒!7q߮▒u^▒▒^▒Y1▒S▒6s▒^▒^S^ز,▒▒▒S8▒wS▒1▒_▒{^U^▒▒^E` ^▒^▒]▒▒^▒$^P[▒-IfD^▒^▒^▒D`▒tW^@F^TL  ^▒^▒E^]▒@▒^\M   !▒^B&^òc!^@e`92$
▒▒▒)l▒^▒8▒^Gn3^▒A^▒^M7▒▒▒u^_▒▒ٱ^_▒▒^▒▒fG^▒^▒^▒^T/V^▒^M^▒^▒!V▒▒~▒^S▒^▒▒^▒E^WO^▒▒jY7&▒▒▒g//▒C▒▒^▒ٮ^▒?W*▒}▒▒▒▒÷^Ou$^@/M=▒^?▒X▒o▒▒▒▒g▒^Ļ▒^_^C▒▒▒▒^▒<▒^?▒s^K5^▒(Ks▒▒^ٳ▒▒;$
▒▒_▒▒▒▒.▒^▒▒▒ed▒-▒Ox|7▒"^O^^▒▒▒▒^M▒▒▒*|▒^U▒▒^▒^K▒R▒߼▒%I▒▒C?▒^▒f^\^▒^U+h*▒▒A▒▒▒f^▒Y^D▒^▒.^\<▒▒▒▒▒^W^▒ J▒^MAx▒^K^▒▒^▒▒^@I▒~^▒▒x :^NF^N▒^U▒g^▒}9▒1▒^B▒xG^P^D\^▒^D^▒1@,▒^▒m▒,^^▒+▒^$
;       ^▒▒/^▒^▒<^Q$▒^S*2▒"▒^▒  ^▒▒S@▒#^▒&^▒xbZ<^Rm^▒^]^▒G▒RMB^▒▒;"▒A▒^▒^M5▒{▒O▒^▒▒p▒▒▒^F"ѱ▒/▒l▒^▒7^E^L'▒▒P▒b▒'▒▒p▒Ѵ▒▒^▒▒^▒▒▒^▒n▒▒;Z^▒^B▒.▒▒v^▒▒ewwVhFD▒▒▒8Po^]^▒T▒ϴr?$
▒>^M▒^▒I▒^▒▒^_^E,c^▒^▒▒▒g▒o▒wX▒^S|^V▒g▒k▒▒^?▒▒^▒P▒▒^H▒W▒/>▒?▒E▒^▒▒_▒^Ez^S▒_▒^?n▒▒^▒▒▒▒▒^˼^▒▒_▒y▒MB_▒}^▒▒▒;▒C~F~b▒▒▒O^A▒<▒^S▒▒?^O▒▒▒▒^O▒▒▒*▒ $▒{▒▒O^G^▒Q▒▒^P▒▒^S?^▒^A▒▒▒▒#▒T1$
^▒^▒(^▒e[b"^T^E^[^Q▒▒▒^L+^▒OLB^P▒^\▒▒^@▒&oV^Ϩ(^@^O-^D▒laG▒,^S▒^E▒$^▒^Ţ▒%\    `^▒,▒^▒c▒▒▒;޳^▒XϺ▒.^T▒^ѷ▒^▒▒%▒▒Q▒▒^Ma
Y▒1▒x?^[▒^R7^▒^V▒P▒^A▒^▒▒^▒̭▒▒▒▒▒^▒^ߢcF▒}^[▒▒^▒▒U▒{▒▒b#^▒▒▒^▒L▒▒r_?▒Aw2^▒f▒uλ▒%.:^▒$!▒▒^^▒▒T▒^M^▒^@^▒^˩|^▒▒^▒     Z8^H▒,<%Q▒▒\^▒lM^Cj3^Y▒k▒^▒D▒ͶPGQ>^▒^▒n▒zR▒▒p^▒^ܥ▒!▒^$
]+^T▒^@▒Qs^_.▒^▒n▒-▒^▒^\^▒G▒▒*5▒8▒?\p;qܰhk9حr^S6▒^U.▒^Ƶ1J▒^@^O▒o▒^▒▒^▒Wv▒▒,0▒2F^▒▒▒O\▒{\▒▒▒▒^▒tC▒^▒2▒զ^▒^A^▒▒▒L▒^▒V▒^WG^A▒$▒▒=▒^▒^By▒▒▒^▒7▒▒=▒?^Ư▒^_\*^▒<▒▒{▒^O▒▒▒*▒▒▒^S$
▒▒Z^T▒y^Poq}q▒Ũ▒p▒n▒^▒x▒^▒T8▒▒Z▒|▒^߻^▒S▒T^T▒l^N▒Jj▒ݯ^▒▒▒u^▒^▒n^R▒▒W▒▒<^ؿ   ^]▒▒▒▒▒▒?^@^▒▒▒?!^O▒▒.▒W▒▒>▒8e/▒▒E▒▒O^_#z▒▒_▒gP1▒▒^Y▒▒V▒^▒^L▒▒▒▒;^C^^▒D^?F>O▒^▒▒^L~S^K^▒^▒▒▒^▒$
Sz▒Z▒▒▒^?▒▒w▒▒1▒▒▒▒R^Q▒3▒▒▒▒?▒^ϩ▒^ݴz;▒▒^J▒}▒^^@^P▒^▒▒^▒^Br^B^▒H^֤▒^▒^A@f^V^▒ILI^Pe^▒X<v^H0▒^Mx▒^X▒▒ ^▒1^▒^▒▒^▒!(^R▒^Q▒A^Hc^Le^▒^D^▒▒▒^R^]d
Dv /
P^▒/▒▒^E^Ʊ(ȲD▒▒^▒^A▒+▒^Ŧ^T▒W^▒;^G▒^▒▒*o▒▒▒X/▒y^¤^YZ^▒\/▒b^▒1▒O55N▒'▒[^▒▒i&^▒^AW^G▒^H▒▒t^G^Z▒^Vsݺ▒^▒}u▒ݯWp▒5▒E^ZL<^ųO▒r▒0E^XL^U▒s0▒}▒^▒^S                w▒▒~4JA^Q▒q▒-Ϋ^▒&^P▒^O}$
MM▒W8▒  <˿▒^E▒O▒? ^P^▒^@▒▒?D^▒^G▒{^O▒j▒▒^_▒Ul^_▒▒?^▒▒▒▒{^W▒▒^?w▒▒#▒▒▒▒W▒9/▒>▒?▒̲2N▒Z▒e▒▒o▒▒y^▒▒^[▒^▒^POn⻥K▒▒▒^X^N X^▒▒▒▒.f▒&b<^ϰ%▒^@▒^▒#^ѻT▒j8▒▒                ▒▒▒▒▒^]^Y]b3▒j^\$
$^▒▒▒^G▒8^F^^f▒=>^V▒▒▒ C▒j^U^ִ^▒^NO▒▒▒^▒▒^▒^▒^▒▒^P^S^▒k▒^\^K▒:▒▒^▒^▒u▒▒V▒▒ú^U^▒▒▒<h^^`^▒s▒^▒v▒Y2V^▒-▒▒^▒▒2▒^O^▒`▒▒:E^^^▒^▒▒]▒^▒▒&▒▒▒^P^٭b▒^▒6^[^▒6<{ۦ▒▒c▒▒a▒^T▒▒▒^▒▒^$
'▒
#A3do^޵z^K▒ c▒;^[▒^Ϧg▒9,^Kv*UH▒Nq^*=9^U▒`^Wc▒%^▒▒F^Q▒^▒▒<^@▒^▒_^▒▒▒^▒^▒x▒;▒^[▒▒▒▒▒^@▒▒▒     ^O^^▒▒▒"▒▒▒▒^▒jD▒^▒?"4▒▒^Q^▒▒o▒▒▒▒▒▒^D^S(^P^A]▒b^▒^^▒▒=▒v▒^?O▒▒^▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒#$^▒▒▒$
▒^?V^▒^_B^?ۼ^▒▒^▒n^C▒X^ԧfP^۰▒Ź^[▒▒Z+^N+xZS▒▒[▒>^▒^ײ^▒eY▒c/▒▒V ^R$7=▒@%▒J▒bS$▒^▒^XB^Bl▒^▒E)▒^▒^R^Vlʬ▒nGB^▒mZ▒^F^R▒▒D^▒^▒lѴyɮ^@^▒#c^@^E J&^▒   ▒[L▒^Ds^▒^V^▒l^F02MS▒Aʧ$
`7^Z▒N▒0^▒w▒^▒58fPtPfh^▒▒~?▒▒^▒^X▒wZ^ں'~▒m^[E▒i55g^?^ֻ$:+▒l^▒▒▒z▒^▒f▒Y▒^▒▒^Fy^?▒/▒▒^P▒]▒^W^X▒▒^▒▒`mA!▒ey▒:H▒vaw:g%L▒▒7Ϡ5^▒V▒H▒^▒I^▒Y¸▒▒\▒▒^▒^▒x▒▒D>^D▒^Ŷ▒^▒▒▒^▒^Q^▒G^▒m$
.▒▒C^V▒▒S▒^▒^^X▒/▒▒R▒▒.▒jq^▒'E^;xf^▒]"▒_n▒(Ci▒▒▒▒^▒?▒▒^▒▒/▒▒^^▒▒0>▒^▒|▒▒^?^▒^K▒-▒/@▒~▒?▒^?▒^Ӽ▒▒▒▒▒C^W▒▒▒▒^]`▒c>{^AZ&▒▒q▒^▒ת▒$▒e         ▒^▒▒1▒S▒^׬V▒^▒Q^▒▒EP]ͽ^▒e▒▒
^▒^▒^▒▒▒<^▒^▒▒BP^R▒r▒▒=aD▒z~▒▒1`U^▒A^▒m"ˢ▒$▒^H^D▒^▒ `^YVz▒_CJn^\^C▒$Q&▒^▒I6^▒^Q▒^]"3▒^˲^̡$^P^▒^Q"RǶ Om^^▒▒p▒E b^▒▒WoH▒▒▒U▒V^Z▒^ޢ▒U%X▒^Ԭ^▒▒▒^_c▒▒▒▒V▒^[M▒^Z▒^▒b▒▒d^S^\^Lv▒$
Z^گu▒^▒Q{<^T;R=▒^▒^▒▒▒D▒▒▒l4^▒^▒^V▒m35▒v>^S▒3^▒^Fy▒:▒▒`^]4▒Sd^˧B:▒^ѩ*▒sGn▒S▒^▒^▒▒T▒D▒▒XNW▒e/^X^г^▒^VHY/▒▒▒P6Fæ▒▒ȸ˲b{^N:▒▒q^▒▒
▒^▒▒&9▒^R)8^▒^\^\u▒U▒ͻ▒▒5^▒▒^C;▒^▒^▒^▒▒▒^▒"▒▒6^▒▒▒^▒▒~▒▒WG▒^▒▒4D^▒N▒▒▒L/▒▒۷▒▒l▒▒▒^▒Ѿ▒^▒▒>b▒▒▒7▒^▒▒^▒^▒5^U▒~
z*=^▒!▒▒^▒▒o▒▒)¤^▒(▒v▒^DfOr▒qv^?nHc^▒=o▒x^[▒k▒▒^▒▒▒▒}▒▒▒F^HK^▒̿^N"l^▒i▒▒▒G^\zlW3▒8O?^▒^RZ▒▒^W▒▒^▒^R-▒▒I|F▒▒▒^?^V▒^S^Q^RQ^D/▒^▒▒▒ۻ▒▒▒▒3▒?^Ex?▒^X>▒^?▒G▒[▒▒^▒^▒Z▒^▒▒=;▒|▒2^W$
▒▒Ħ▒^▒e▒▒▒G^▒\OB_▒^▒▒^F9▒^Q'X▒q▒aqO▒▒▒▒(▒^^O5▒▒^▒▒^W▒▒׳I^NV▒ap<i^V^Z1▒v^▒▒n▒^▒^▒Ot▒n▒&^@▒▒▒▒hc`▒
e^▒'qw▒▒[^▒▒;▒▒▒)▒^▒Y^▒^Y▒▒^▒s'▒1▒^ʼ▒▒1▒^_^S▒▒m^▒^U▒uv▒^▒^▒i{▒^▒O^▒~i^▒`▒H▒Ӷ▒▒GQ^_^[LNi^▒▒u▒^▒=q^Z^Y^_▒6Vo^E^▒d^V▒~[▒e^Ǭ\Y▒▒▒^C^S▒;n▒^C^▒5▒0;^Hj^^^▒▒b3^]▒=Z▒▒^▒▒▒^▒w▒nW^[Qy$
▒▒n▒▒2^O▒6yY▒^?Z▒▒▒▒▒o^W▒▒▒'▒^Y?▒▒^D^▒^▒▒▒H@@▒U|▒▒^D<▒▒▒E^▒▒o
^@}^K▒▒@▒^▒^?,^▒^▒▒^?^W▒▒▒▒'▒▒^^r'w▒▒▒$^@▒^▒▒▒▒▒▒▒^▒У▒▒▒▒^M▒▒U^▒^_▒▒▒m▒▒▒▒^▒/▒f^̦▒U^▒▒a^Rxf^▒^?▒▒t^M^F2▒0▒^▒▒Y▒ff▒,4/%▒▒Z^Rg^▒g^E7^^}^Q@▒&^Q▒▒▒▒;▒^N^U ^?▒^W ^▒"▒d*▒K▒^▒c^Q^$
```

Is there anything I can do without reinstalling the whole OS?

Comment: Have you updated your repository recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is not damaged. It's just... *not a text file.* (It's a tar archive compressed using gzip.)

However, my guess is that you've somehow configured pacman to use the **wrong mirror list**.

Raspberry Pi is an ARM device and *does not run Arch Linux* – instead it runs Arch Linux ARM, which maintains its repositories independently of the x86 distro. Therefore, many mirrors only host the Arch Linux i686 / x86_64 repositories but not the ARM ones (and vice versa).

For example, take a look at what files [mirror.easyname.at](http://mirror.easyname.at/archlinux/core/os/) actually serves. You'll see it does not have any ARM repositories, just i686 and x86_64.

Comment: Thanks, haven't thought of that, used this [list]https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/blob/master/core/pacman-mirrorlist/mirrorlist)